# Custom Style for Button, Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am developing a desktop application using *Python tkinter*. I am facing problems while styling it. Is there any way to get the desired output. It may not be exact but some what similar like: `button` with red/green/yellow background, `treeview` with grid-lines. I have tried

```
customed_style.configure('Custom.TButton', font=('Helvetica', 11), background="red", foreground='white')

customed_style.configure("Custom.Treeview.Heading", background="blue", foreground="white", relief="flat", font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
```

But these don't make the desired output, these only changes the text color to white but not the background.

I am working on **Windows 10** Operating System

**Desired Style:**
[image: Desired State]

**Current Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Python tkinter ttk Style")
        self.master.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')

        self.frame_buttons = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame_buttons.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky='nesw')

        self.frame_treeview = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame_treeview.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky='nesw')

        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_treeview()

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.details_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='details_button.png').subsample(3, 3)
        self.edit_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='edit_button.png').subsample(3, 3)
        self.delete_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='delete_button.png').subsample(3, 3)

        self.button_details = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="Details", image=self.details_button_image, compound="left", style='Custom.TButton')
        self.button_details.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.button_edit = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="Edit", image=self.edit_button_image, compound="left", style='Custom.TButton')
        self.button_edit.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.button_delete = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="Delete", image=self.delete_button_image, compound="left", style='Custom.TButton')
        self.button_delete.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=4, pady=4)

    def create_treeview(self):
        self.treeview_person_list = ttk.Treeview(self.frame_treeview, columns=('name', 'email', 'contact', 'address'), height=6)
        self.treeview_person_list.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#0', text="ID")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#0", minwidth=50, width=50, anchor='center')
        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#1', text="Full Name")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#1", minwidth=150, width=150, anchor='w')
        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#2', text="Email")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#2", minwidth=150, width=150, anchor='w')
        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#3', text="Phone")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#3", minwidth=150, width=150, anchor='w')
        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#4', text="Street Address")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#4", minwidth=150, width=150, anchor='w')

        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='01', values=('Annabel Geffen', 'ageffen0@hc360.com', '+55 138 953 4728', '34346 6th Pass'))
        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='02', values=('Ailey Myring', 'amyring1@lulu.com', '+234 874 785 2200', '72 Cody Street'))
        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='03', values=('Sherie Meeron', 'smeeron2@xing.com', '+86 348 534 4411', '0896 Express Park'))
        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='04', values=('Alice Grayston', 'agrayston3@phpbb.com', '+51 591 958 5938', '540 Beilfuss Circle'))
        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='05', values=('Hasheem Halbard', 'hhalbard4@wikia.com', '+593 493 130 1417', '08291 Shasta Parkway'))


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    customed_style = ttk.Style()
    customed_style.configure('Custom.TButton', font=('Helvetica', 11))

    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Current Style:**
[image: Current State]

**With Custom Style Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Python tkinter ttk Style")
        self.master.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')

        self.frame_buttons = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame_buttons.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky='nesw')

        self.frame_treeview = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame_treeview.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=4, pady=4, sticky='nesw')

        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_treeview()

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.details_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='details_button.png').subsample(3, 3)
        self.edit_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='edit_button.png').subsample(3, 3)
        self.delete_button_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='delete_button.png').subsample(3, 3)

        self.button_details = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="Details", image=self.details_button_image, compound="left", style='Custom.TButton')
        self.button_details.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.button_edit = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="Edit", image=self.edit_button_image, compound="left", style='Custom.TButton')
        self.button_edit.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.button_delete = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="Delete", image=self.delete_button_image, compound="left", style='Custom.TButton')
        self.button_delete.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=4, pady=4)

    def create_treeview(self):
        self.treeview_person_list = ttk.Treeview(self.frame_treeview, columns=('name', 'email', 'contact', 'address'), height=6, style='Custom.Treeview')
        self.treeview_person_list.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#0', text="ID")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#0", minwidth=50, width=50, anchor='center')
        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#1', text="Full Name")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#1", minwidth=150, width=150, anchor='w')
        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#2', text="Email")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#2", minwidth=150, width=150, anchor='w')
        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#3', text="Phone")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#3", minwidth=150, width=150, anchor='w')
        self.treeview_person_list.heading('#4', text="Street Address")
        self.treeview_person_list.column("#4", minwidth=150, width=150, anchor='w')

        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='01', values=('Annabel Geffen', 'ageffen0@hc360.com', '+55 138 953 4728', '34346 6th Pass'), tag='odd')
        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='02', values=('Ailey Myring', 'amyring1@lulu.com', '+234 874 785 2200', '72 Cody Street'), tag='even')
        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='03', values=('Sherie Meeron', 'smeeron2@xing.com', '+86 348 534 4411', '0896 Express Park'), tag='odd')
        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='04', values=('Alice Grayston', 'agrayston3@phpbb.com', '+51 591 958 5938', '540 Beilfuss Circle'), tag='even')
        self.treeview_person_list.insert('', 'end', text='05', values=('Hasheem Halbard', 'hhalbard4@wikia.com', '+593 493 130 1417', '08291 Shasta Parkway'), tag='odd')

        self.treeview_person_list.tag_configure('odd', background='#F5F5F5')
        self.treeview_person_list.tag_configure('even', background='#FFFFFF')


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    customed_style = ttk.Style()
    customed_style.configure('Custom.TButton', font=('Helvetica', 11), background="red", foreground='white')
    customed_style.configure('Custom.Treeview', highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Helvetica', 10))
    customed_style.configure('Custom.Treeview.Heading', font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'), background="blue", foreground="red")

    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**With Custom Style:**
[image: Not Desired State]

If anyone wants to try with the images also here are the three images used in the code:

details_button: 
[image] 
edit_button: 
[image] 
delete_button: 
[image]

Any good resource on complete custom styling for *Python tkinter ttk* will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [Styles and Themes](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html)

Comment: @stovfl I have read this. And then I tried the custom style for button which is given in the question. That doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You seem to be using images with transparent text and an icon, so just paint them (background of the image, I mean) on your choice. Your question is not complete without these images.

Comment: @stovfl I have updated my question with the image of state after applying custom style. Please check.

Comment: @CommonSense Yes, I have both `text` and `image` in `button` but not in `treeview.heading`. Image is not important. Only White text with colored background will solve my problem.

Comment: @Partho63: Checked! Works for me, `Button`: **red** background, **white** text, **black** image. `Treeview`: **blue** background, **red** text. I'm on Linux, couldn't check on Windows. Try with different `Themes`, I could for example, only with `Theme clam`, set the border color of a `Button`.

Comment: @stovfl So I guess this is happening because I'm on Windows. Thanks for your help. Is it possible to make an universal design? Can you give me any suggestion/resources to follow so that I can make a design which will be **Universal for all different Operating Systems**.

Comment: Relevant [how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python) and [ttk-themes-available-based-on-the-operating-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664085/are-python-tkinter-ttk-themes-available-based-on-the-operating-system)